# Migration of portlets in Liferay

Tags: liferay

I have to deploy my portlets in Liferay 6.1 ga2 to Liferay 6.1 ga3.

I have tried doing it but it's not getting deployed. Database connection is done. Web contents are showing but the portlet part it is showing "Portlet undeployed. Please redeploy it."

I am new in Liferay. Can anyone please guide me step by step?

Thanks in advance.

Here is the log:

```
16:15:31,436 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/my_project].[default]] (ajp-/0.0.0.0:8009-4) JBWEB000236: Servlet.service() for servlet default threw exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException: JBWEB000088: The requested resource (/my-project/my-portlet/invoke) is not available
    at org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet.serveResource(DefaultServlet.java:651) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet.doGet(DefaultServlet.java:338) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet.doPost(DefaultServlet.java:374) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72) [portal-service.jar:]
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:73) [portal-service.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:832) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:718) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:655) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.jsp.html.portal.extend_005fsession_jsp._jspService(extend_005fsession_jsp.java:411)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:69) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:365) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:309) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:242) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72) [portal-service.jar:]
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116) [portal-service.jar:]
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:73) [portal-service.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:832) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:620) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:553) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:482) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at com.liferay.portal.struts.StrutsUtil.forward(StrutsUtil.java:79) [portal-impl.jar:]
    at com.liferay.portal.struts.PortalRequestProcessor.doForward(PortalRequestProcessor.java:282) [portal-impl.jar:]
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.internalModuleRelativeForward(RequestProcessor.java:1023) [apache-struts-1.2.4.jar:1.2.4]
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.internalModuleRelativeForward(TilesRequestProcessor.java:345) [struts-tiles-1.3.5.jar:1.3.5]
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForward(RequestProcessor.java:572) [apache-struts-1.2.4.jar:1.2.4]
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:221) [apache-struts-1.2.4.jar:1.2.4]
    at com.liferay.portal.struts.PortalRequestProcessor.process(PortalRequestProcessor.java:176) [portal-impl.jar:]
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196) [apache-struts-1.2.4.jar:1.2.4]
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432) [apache-struts-1.2.4.jar:1.2.4]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.callParentService(MainServlet.java:560) [portal-impl.jar:]
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:537) [portal-impl.jar:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72) [portal-service.jar:]
    at ... (shortened)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol$AjpConnectionHandler.process(AjpProtocol.java:420) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:920) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_38]

16:17:31,500 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/WESTBENGAL-SSDG-WEBSERVICES].[default]] (ajp-/0.0.0.0:8009-11) JBWEB000236: Servlet.service() for servlet default threw exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException: JBWEB000088: The requested resource (/WESTBENGAL-SSDG-WEBSERVICES/WESTBENGAL-SSDG-WEBSERVICES/invoke) is not available
    at org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet.serveResource(DefaultServlet.java:651) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet.doGet(DefaultServlet.java:338) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet.doPost(DefaultServlet.java:374) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72) [portal-service.jar:]
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:73) [portal-service.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:832) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:718) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:655) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.jsp.html.portal.extend_005fsession_jsp._jspService(extend_005fsession_jsp.java:411)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:69) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:365) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:309) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:242) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72) [portal-service.jar:]
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116) [portal-service.jar:]
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:73) [portal-service.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:832) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:620) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:553) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:482) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at com.liferay.portal.struts.StrutsUtil.forward(StrutsUtil.java:79) [portal-impl.jar:]
    at com.liferay.portal.struts.PortalRequestProcessor.doForward(PortalRequestProcessor.java:282) [portal-impl.jar:]
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.internalModuleRelativeForward(RequestProcessor.java:1023) [apache-struts-1.2.4.jar:1.2.4]
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.internalModuleRelativeForward(TilesRequestProcessor.java:345) [struts-tiles-1.3.5.jar:1.3.5]
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForward(RequestProcessor.java:572) [apache-struts-1.2.4.jar:1.2.4]
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:221) [apache-struts-1.2.4.jar:1.2.4]
    at ... (shortened)
```

Comment: Please provide console errors @ time of portlet deployment

Comment: I will provide the log as soon as I start the other server. But what I recall from the previous log is, that there were some library issues. Anyway, shall post the log soon.

Comment: Look at liferay-plugin-package.xml in order to find if the portlet has dependencies from other plugins such as hooks and portlets por need some jars.

Comment: I just checked, but there is a .properties file with the same name but no .xml file.

Comment: and what do you find in the properties file? It might be obvious. Anyway, let's continue when you know more than "I have problems" - e.g. when you post the actual messages from the log file. So far this is by far not enough information

Comment: here is my detailed server log file :

Comment: They are not letting me post the entire log. Do I have to do it part by part or is there some better option, like upload the file.

Comment: 13:51:01,130 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/WESTBENGAL-SSDG-WEBSERVICES].[default]] (ajp-/0.0.0.0:8009-1) JBWEB000236: Servlet.service() for servlet default threw exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException: JBWEB000088:

Comment: The requested resource (/WESTBENGAL-SSDG-WEBSERVICES/WESTBENGAL-SSDG-WEBSERVICES/invoke) is not available
 at org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet.serveResource(DefaultServlet.java:651) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]

Comment: You can [edit](/posts/30636010/edit) your original query and add all relevant information there.

Comment: Done. Kindly check the log now.

Answer (score 1):

This is my way:

1. Create new portlet with same name by Liferay sdk 6.1.2.
2. Copy your code, html, resources, libs from old portlet to new portlet.
3. Copy portlets declaration in `portlet.xml`, `liferay-portlet.xml` and `liferay-display.xml`, from old portlet to new portlet (don't overwrite these files).
4. Deploy new portlet.

Answer (score 0):

Portlet Upgradation Steps to be followed.

1. Upgrade the version of liferay in liferay-plugin-package.properties file. (Please note liferay-plugin-package.xml file is created at runtime by liferay)
2. Upgrade the corresponding liferay DTD version in liferay-display.xml, liferay-portlet.xml files. (This is an optional in certain scenarios)
3. Upgrade the portlet code as per new API classes/methods/parameters etc.

If still it fails, please let me know.

Comment: See I have tried all this. I will certainly do it again. I have to migrate my entire project to this other server.

So I really can't do anything about the code. 

I will try checking my .xml files.

Comment: Hi.
Well, I tried everything and now the server log is giving a database related error. But this particular error was solved too. 
Still, the server is showing the same error.

Comment: JBWEB004060: An error occurred at line: 268 in the jsp file: /html/portlet/journal_content/view.jsp
The local variable connection may not have been initialized
265:            }catch(Exception e ){
266:            }finally{
267:             statement.close();
268:             connection.close();
269:            }
270:

Comment: Riya can't help you like this, if required you can mail me details at neerajgautam011@gmail.com. Once issue is fixed, you can update this stackoverflow page with solution.